# How has google play music disabled illegal downloading of audio streams?

Tags: html, security, audio

I was just playing some Bowie off google play music on my PC and became curious as to how they have stopped illegal downloading. The All Access feature of google play means you can listen to any music on their servers for a fixed fee a month so I figured they must have a mechanism to stop users downloading anything they're streaming.

I opened up the network log and opened the URL of the audio stream in another tab. It opened fine and showed the MP3 play buttons as expected but the play button does nothing. I understand they will probably be using some kind of cookie method to stop hotlinking but that doesn't mean you can't download it shortly after you've clicked play in the play music client. Its been racking my mind for a while now and I can't think how they might have done it. They seemingly just use the new HTML5 features to play all audio.

Does anyone have any insight into how the genius' at google have done this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your computer can play the song, it can be recorded (e.g. Freecorder). This is similar to recording songs off the radio onto cassette tape.

It's possible to pirate the songs, but if they make it easy and cheap enough for you to buy the music, they hope you'll just buy it.

Besides, there are PSAs that tell you how illegal and wrong it is to pirate music.

Comment: I am aware of this and I am not trying to pirate music off google play I assure you. I am thinking of incorporating music downloads into a website I am working on. I have made it difficult enough but google seem to have made it REALLy difficult so I just wandered how.